# Parse: PFUser subclass always returns <PFUser> object

Tags: ios, parsing, subclassing

I've got a subclass of PFUser called LPUser:

```
// LPUser.h

#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface LPUser : PFUser<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) NSString firstName;
@property (retain) NSString lastName;

 + (LPUser *)currentUser;

@end



// LPUser.m

#import "LPUser.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation LPUser

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;

+ (LPUser *)currentUser
{
    return (LPUser *)[PFUser currentUser];
}

@end


// AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [LPUser registerSubclass];

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"<< APP ID >>"
                  clientKey:@" << CLIENT KEY >>"];
    return YES;
}
```

My problem is that any calls to LPUser (currentUser, user or object) all return a PFUser object instead of LPUser.. even if I cast it like `LPUser user = (LPUser*)[LPUser object]`.

What am I doing wrong in setting up my subclass?

I get this when I NSLog user:

```
2014-05-08 13:46:39.879[21529:60b] user: <PFUser:new:(null)> {

}
```

Comment: did you tried to: + (LPUser *)currentUser { return self; } ????? if your object is subclass of PFUser and you return self you return the current user...

Comment: I can't return self as this is a class method. I think that registerSubclass isn't working but not sure why..

Comment: yeah , i miss the + char, anyway what's your goal why your doing this like that ?

Comment: debug it line by line, I'm sure you didn't init your object correctly

Answer (score 0):

`return (LPUser *)[PFUser currentUser]` is not creating a new object but just forwarding whatever the `PFUser` class returns from its `+currentUser` class method.

As there is no code for that method in your code I suppose that it either returns a static `PFUser` instance, probably set by a `setCurrentUser` method on the same class.

Anyway both `LPUser` and `PFUser` return the same object so you can't have different class instances for each one with your current implementation.

Comment: Ok, I came to the conclusion that (according to posts on parse's support forum) calling `[LPUser registerSubClass]` should make a subsequent call to `(LPUser *)[PFUser currentUser]` return your custom PFUser object instead of a PFUser.. guess it doesn't then?